# JavaScript - automatic launch the method

Tags: javascript

I have a form:

```
<tr>
<td class="td_left">Repeat password</td>
<td class="td_right"><input type="password" 
value="DEFAULT"
name="repass" size="40" id="repass_id" 
onkeypress="CorrectPass('repass_id')" onfocus="CorrectPass('repass_id')" 
onkeyup="CorrectPass('repass_id')" value="" /></td>
<td class="td_info"><div id="repass_correct"></div></td>
</tr>
```

When I click mouse in this field, begin launch method "CorrectPass('repass_id')". But I want, that this method launch automatic allways when I load this page

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function ()
   {
      CorrectPass('repass_id');
   };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the body tag.

```
<body onload="CorrectPass('repass_id')">
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically launch a script simply write it between  tags, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CorrectPass('repass_id')
</script>
```

Put it anywhere in your document - best between `<head>` and `</head>`

Comment: You should, however I am glad that helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

> But I want, that this method launch automatic allways when I load
>   this page

```
window.onload = function() {
  CorrectPass('repass_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery and want to run this function after full load of the DOM tree, than use

```
$(function() { CorrectPass('repass_id') });
```